# How can i create backup/restore in React Native project?

Tags: react-native, backup

I created a React Native app for personal purposes and this app is about books. I don't use any back-end for my app. I just have a JSON file in which all book info is stored in there. now for avoid data losing, I want to create backup & restore feature in my app.

I need to create a backup file and save it on my mobile device and use it for restoring data.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `expo-file-system` and save info to `documentDirectory` or `cacheDirectory`.

The content for `writeAsStringAsync` should be `string`. Hence, you might need custom `readParseAsycn` and `writeStringifyAsyc`

**`expo-file-system`: local storage methods and constants with custom read and write**

```js
import * as FileSystem from "expo-file-system";

const {
  deleteAsync,
  documentDirectory,
  cacheDirectory,
  EncodingType,
  getInfoAsync,
  makeDirectoryAsync,
  readAsStringAsync,
  writeAsStringAsync,
  readDirectoryAsync,
} = FileSystem;

const encodingObj = { encoding: EncodingType.UTF8 };

async function readParseAsyc(fileUri) {
  return JSON.parse(await readAsStringAsync(fileUri, encodingObj));
}

function writeStringifyAsyc(fileUri, content) {
  return writeAsStringAsync(fileUri, JSON.stringify(content), encodingObj);
}
```

---

```js
const readWriteSampleAsync = async () => {
  const sampleFileUri = `${documentDirectory}sample.txt`
  await writeStringifyAsyc(sampleFileUri, {sampleArray: ["sample0", "sample1"], sampleBool: false})
  const sampleRead = await readParseAsyc(sampleFileUri)
  console.log(sampleRead )
}
```